# How to pass current model from layout to controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a menu bar that sits in the layout, that every page has access to

I'm trying to save whatever the page model's info is (could be edit info for a customer, or a car, or dog) when the user clicks on one of these menu items, so that when they return to the page - i can refill the info on whatever page they came from.

what is the best way to do something like this?

Right now, and this is ugly - each controller has its own Action for the menu links ("Edit"), the View itself sits on the /Shared folder and the layout has an ActionLink like this

_Layout.vbhtml

```
<div id="footer">                
    <div class="footerContent" style="top:20px;">@Html.ActionLink("Edit This", Edit"</div>
</div>
```

Any Controller that can use this Layout looks like this (eg. ApplyController):

```
    Public Function Edit(ByVal apply As ApplyModel) As ActionResult
        //would like to save the apply model so i can use it later 
        Return View("Edit"))
    End Function
```

Anyways - hope this makes sense..first time using MVC with VB.NET so hopefuly everything looks ok

Comment: You mean having something like ViewState on ASP.net?